# A random exception is sometimes thrown whenever i add a record using entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello so i have a working simple department database wherein the admin can add records( the only functionality that i have right now).

Here are my essential codes:

**Context class:**

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
       List<Department> aDep =  emp.Departments.ToList();

        return View(aDep);
    }

}
```

**Employee Model class:**

```
[Table("carl")]
public class Employee
{


    public int id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Last name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
    public string lastname { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Department")]
    [Range(1, 3)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dep num is required")]
    public int department { get; set; }


}
```

**Controller class:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
        List<Employee> adep = emp.Employees.ToList();

        return View(adep);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)      
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
                Employee entry = new Employee()
                {
                    firstname = form["firstname"],
                    lastname = form["lastname"],
                    department = Convert.ToInt32(form["department"])

                };

                emp.Employees.Add(entry);
                emp.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Response.Write("Failed to Add, please try again");
            }
        }      

        return View();
    }
}
```

My views are just the default templates for `create` and `list`

My problem is that : They work as intended but sometimes, an exception will be thrown and will state that i failed to add my record(this is within my catch statement). So i am not sure if it the error is from my code/structure or from my server itself. What should i do?

edit: I was trying to trigger the error again but it wasn't showing up, i was testing my application earlier and sometimes my catch statement gets executed and i can't add any records after that. The error is entity dll error. I will update once i found it out.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Uhhhh i was trying to generate the error again but it won't show up. The only thing i am sure is that my catch statement is being executed if that ever happens. I will update my post once i trigger the error.

Comment: Any particular reason for you to receive a `FormCollection` in your `Create` action instead of a `Employee`?

Comment: Looks like a Validation error. Can you assign an integer to your department instead of relying on your form value. 
department = Convert.ToInt32(form["department"])

Answer (score 0):

Pass department as an integer object to the Employee data object.

```
int departmentID = 0;
departmentID = Convert.ToInt32(form["department"])

 Employee entry = new Employee()
                {
                    firstname = form["firstname"],
                    lastname = form["lastname"],
                    department = departmentID

                };
```